# TcpListener AcceptSocket() accepts two connections for each single GET request

Tags: c#, webserver, tcplistener

I have this web server program up and running, using TcpListener. The problem is that for each get request made through web browser (or chrome Postman extension), it captures two requests.

```
namespace Server
{
    class WebServer2
    {
        private TcpListener listener;
        private int port = 8080;

        public WebServer2()
        {
            try
            {
                listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
                listener.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Listening...");

                //start the thread which calls the method 'StartListen'
                Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListen));
                th.Start();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An Exception Occurred While Listening: " + e.ToString());
            }
        }

        //Recieve Request
        public void StartListen()
        {
            int iStartPos = 0;
            String sRequest;
            String sRequestedFile;
            String sResponse = "";

            while (true)
            {
                //Accept a new connection
                Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();

                if (socket.Connected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nClient Connected");
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------");

                    //Receive data from the client 
                    Byte[] bReceive = new Byte[1024];
                    int i = socket.Receive(bReceive, bReceive.Length, 0);

                    //Convert Byte to String
                    string sBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bReceive);

                    //Only GET Request is accepted
                    if (sBuffer.Substring(0, 3) != "GET")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not a Get Request.");
                        socket.Close();
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Look for HTTP request
                    iStartPos = sBuffer.IndexOf("HTTP", 1);

                    // Get the HTTP text and version e.g. it will return "HTTP/1.1"
                    string sHttpVersion = sBuffer.Substring(iStartPos, 8);

                    // Extract the Requested Type and Requested file/directory
                    sRequest = sBuffer.Substring(0, iStartPos - 1);

                    //If file name not provided
                    if (sRequest.IndexOf(".") < 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("File name not Provided!");
                        socket.Close();
                        continue;
                    }

                    //Extract the requested file name
                    iStartPos = sRequest.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
                    sRequestedFile = sRequest.Substring(iStartPos);
                    Console.WriteLine("Requested File: " + sRequestedFile);

                    int iTotBytes = 0;
                    sResponse = "";

                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(sRequestedFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = reader.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        // Read from the file and write the data to the network
                        sResponse = sResponse + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, read);
                        iTotBytes = iTotBytes + read;
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    fs.Close();

                    SendHeader(sHttpVersion, "text/html", iTotBytes, " 200 OK", ref socket);
                    SendToBrowser(bytes, ref socket);

                    socket.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, 0);
                    socket.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        // Overloaded Function, takes string, convert to bytes and calls 
        // overloaded sendToBrowserFunction.
        public void SendToBrowser(String sData, ref Socket socket)
        {
            SendToBrowser(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sData), ref socket);
        }

        /// Sends data to the browser (client)
        public void SendToBrowser(Byte[] bSendData, ref Socket socket)
        {
            int numBytes = 0;

            try
            {
                if (socket.Connected)
                {
                    if ((numBytes = socket.Send(bSendData, bSendData.Length, 0)) == -1)
                        Console.WriteLine("Socket Error");
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection Dropped!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} ", e);
            }
        }

        // This function send the Header Information to the client (Browser)
        public void SendHeader(string sHttpVersion, string sMIMEHeader, int iTotBytes, string sStatusCode, ref Socket socket)
        {

            String sBuffer = "";
            Byte[] bSendData;

            if (sStatusCode.Equals("404") || sStatusCode.Equals("400"))
            {
                sBuffer = sBuffer + sHttpVersion + sStatusCode + "\r\n";
                sBuffer = sBuffer + "Server: MyServer\r\n";
                sBuffer = sBuffer + "Content-Length: " + 0 + "\r\n\r\n";

                bSendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sBuffer);

                SendToBrowser(bSendData, ref socket);
            }
            else
            {
                sBuffer = sBuffer + sHttpVersion + sStatusCode + "\r\n";
                sBuffer = sBuffer + "Server: MyServer\r\n";
                sBuffer = sBuffer + "Content-Type: " + sMIMEHeader + "\r\n";
                sBuffer = sBuffer + "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n";
                sBuffer = sBuffer + "Content-Length: " + iTotBytes + "\r\n\r\n";

                bSendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sBuffer);

                SendToBrowser(bSendData, ref socket);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Single request made by chrome against http://localhost:8080/page1.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRsN6.png)

[Request made by Postman Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqebi.png)

The funny thing is, everything works find when I send request through my client program (using TcpClient).

Answer (score 0):

I tested your server and got similar results:

- Chrome automatically asks for a favicon.ico file for every request. This generates the extra GET request to your server.
- Firefox doesn't do this and simply generates one request per refresh.

Then there is a second problem I experienced, which is the one in your Postman screenshot.

- Chrome (including the Postman **Extension** running inside it) reconnects
  without sending anything, so the server "hangs" until you get a
  response filled with \0 (nul-characters).
- This is part of Chrome's prediction service to load subsequent requests faster. You could disable this behavior under Settings (advanced) > Privacy:

[image: Chrome's prediction service option]

- In your server implementation, this results in the "Not a Get Request" output if no subsequent GET request follows (instead, Chrome sends \0 to signal its not sending anything anyway).

Note: I didn't experience any of this in the actual Postman [application](https://www.getpostman.com/).

While the server waits for chrome to send a request, it cannot service any other requests. To prevent this from happening, consider using an [asynchronous approach](https://gist.github.com/joeandaverde/3994603).

Comment: I never knew that
http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#favicon
<br/>
I still not understand the second problem you mentioned.
Why the chrome reconnects? @Sigge

Comment: This is part of Chrome's prediction services. I edited my answer to clarify and how to disable it. Your server would have to take this in account (by using async processing for example).